# What is the difference between "return <Stream>" and "yield* <Stream>" in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I noticed some strange behaviour of streams when working with `Streams` in Flutter.

**Setup**

An `EventChannel` provides a stream of events.
In my `Cubit` I listen on that stream and cancel the `StreamSubscription` in the `close` method of the `Cubit`.
The next screen also uses the same `EventChannel` to listen for events.
When I enter the second screen, the `onCancel` method in Android was called twice and therefore no events where passed through to the second `Cubit`.
The `Scanner` is a singleton, so both `Cubits` use the same instance.

*Function for the Stream*

```dart
class Scanner {
  final eventChannel = EventChannel("events");

  Stream<ScanEvent> getScanEvent() {
    return _scanEvents.receiveBroadcastStream().map((event) => ScanEvent.fromJson(jsonDecode(event)));
  }
}
```

*Code in the Cubits*

```dart
Scanner scanner = get<Scanner>();

Future<void> listenForScan() async {
  _streamSubscription = _scanner.getScanEvent().listen((event) => submitSerialText(event.scanData));
}

@override
Future<void> close() {
  _streamSubscription?.cancel();
  return super.close();
}
```

**Fix**

When I use `async*` with `yield*` like so it works:

*Fixed Function for the Stream*

```dart
class Scanner {
  final eventChannel = EventChannel("events");

  Stream<ScanEvent> getScanEvent() async* {
    yield* _scanEvents.receiveBroadcastStream().map((event) => ScanEvent.fromJson(jsonDecode(event)));
  }
}
```

**Question**

Why is the stream in the first approach canceled twice?

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQBpOIHE4eE&ab_channel=Flutter) might help. Also read the [this](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams) one.

Comment: That's a good overview of streams, but doesn't answer the question, why the first "returned" stream gets canceled twice.

Comment: Could this be by any chance due to code in cubit? I have no experience with cubit. But the steam part looks fine to me.